# Hive JMX Metrics Enable

Tags: hadoop, hive, prometheus

How we can enable JMX metrics for hive so we monitor it through Prometheus. I can't find any article regarding the same.
Can someone help me regarding the same ?

Comment: would you please give us more information?

Answer (score 0):

Add Prometheus JMX configuration in hive-env.sh file

```
if [ "$SERVICE" = "hiveserver2" ]; then
  export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="$HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9005 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -javaagent:/opt/java_metrics/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=9008:/opt/java_metrics/config.yml -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
fi
if [ "$SERVICE" = "metastore" ]; then
    export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9025 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -javaagent:/opt/java_metrics/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=9028:/opt/java_metrics/config.yml -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  $HEAP_OPTS"
fi
```

Restart hive-server2 and metastore service

Hive-Server2 metrics in prometheus format  will be available in `http://<hive-server2-ip>:9008`

Hive-Metastore metrics in prometheus format will be available in `http://<hive-metastore-ip>:9028`